# Most ethical red-colored wood to purchase?

Tags: wood

Red-colored woods such as padauk, bloodwood, etc.

I want a red-colored wood for a future project, but I do not want to contribute to unsustainable deforestation or exploitation of the local community.

Which is the most reliably ethically sourced one? If it varies widely, what kind of information should I ask for from my local supplier?

If the answer is "none," I can accept that and will likely just use good ol' walnut.

Comment: Simple answer is there ain't one. Very similar to the thing if one wants a violet wood though, there *are* dyes, and you can get a much more consistent, long-lasting red (and a true red, not just reddish, if that's what you'd really like) using them. This also has the advantage, as with purpleheart, of greatly lesser cost since you'll be starting with a domestic wood that's pale in colour.

Answer (score 1):

There are several wood certification and sustainable forestry programs that you can research. But only a small amount of the world's forests are protected by such programs.

You will have to research the relevant programs and find a supplier who claims they can source one of types of lumber you are interested in in compliance with one or more of these programs.

That is, if ethically sourcing lumber is important to you, you will have to start by finding suppliers in your area that claim compliance with one or more of these programs and see which one of those species is more likely to be available to you in the amounts you need.

Because it isn't the species that makes it "ethical". It is the process by which global markets turn forests into wood products we can buy that makes the lumber "ethical" as defined by the programs.

Links discussing the details of such things will be dead in an internet minute. But as of this writing these are some common programs that those of us buying smaller amounts of lumber will likely run into (at least for the kinds of lumber I think you are interested in):

- Forest Stewardship Council
- Sustainable Forestry Initiative
- Programme for the Endorsement of Forest Certification

(The US and Canada have domestic programs for the typical wood products harvested in North America.)

Unfortunately, you are in a tough place if you do not want to buy in the 1000s of board-feet. Many of these programs have harvest schedules based on orders, where specific trees are harvested and sold, probably as green flitches, on demand. You might find a lumberyard with some off-cuts or partial orders.

It might be better to start a relationship with a local yard that can participate in an ethically sourced program, and have them keep an eye out for suitable lumber in the amounts you need.

Comment: +1, but there's a similar issue here to that of "Fairtrade" chocolate (I'm using the quotes very deliberately here). There are some serious questions about whether we can/should trust what we're told about the sources of many/most/all tropical hardwoods from third-world countries *actually* being sustainably managed like we're told. And then of course there are the unknowns about worker conditions, pay etc.

Comment: True enough. Though, the desire to do _something_ is reasonable. Like anything, if these endeavours have enough teeth to actually limit the worst of the greed and short-sightedness then I guess it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: I'm not so sure. Once I found out that the Fairtrade system was so flawed it became obvious it was essentially a sop to Western sensibilities. The wood trade is at least as bad, and from what I've read, **so** much worse (look at what Gibson guitars were up to.... ["It wasn't the first time."](https://text.npr.org/140090116) !!) This is gutting for someone still growing in the hobby who had prior hopes of being able to work with certain exotics, which have to be put aside except for the slim chance of sourcing secondhand (possible with teak; v. unlikely with Rio rosewood, even in small sizes).

Comment: I think the direct purchase arrangements work best. You basically talk to a broker and a mill in Asia and place an order for X board-feet of padauk or whatever and _ideally_ they do the sensible harvesting thing on their schedule. Like, if you are building a sailboat. The more hands this stuff goes through, the easier it is to game. But there are responsible cutters and mills, just not a lot of people actually use them. But there is no way guitar builders and so on will be able to get any of this.

Comment: At this point some of my best lumber is coming from the garbage. I recently repurposed a door from my century home (stored in the basement for years) we knew we were never going to rehang. Part of it is now a workbench, and the other part was resawn into gorgeous, straight, hard-as-a-rock, century seasoned white oak that looks like it was from a 400 year old tree. I do have to play the "let's not turn this into lead dust" game, but I'm already smart enough. I can use a little brain damage.

Comment: *"...but I'm already smart enough. I can use a little brain damage"* Quote of the week! :-))) And yes, any equivalent of "the garbage" is in fact the ideal — and only *truly* ethical — way to acquire some wood species, albeit in very limited amounts in some cases. I always think of ebony here (and the associated ivory, if one is into that) from old clapped-out pianos. Quite apart from the fact that true ebony was one of the first unobtainium woods in 'modern' woodworking (some species effectively disappeared way before our time, including Cuban mahogany) it is inherently so useful a material.